# Check if thread is running

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, winapi

When I declare a HANDLE

```
HANDLE hThread;
```

I make a check to see if the thread is running,

```
  if (WaitForSingleObject(hThread, 0) == WAIT_OBJECT)
  {
       //Thread is not running.
  }
  else
  {
       hThread = CreateThread(......)
  }
```

But it fails for the first time to check if the thread is running. How can it be done? I think the only thing i need is set the `hThread` to signaled state somehow.

### Edit

I have found something like this

```
hThread = CreateEvent(0, 0, 1, 0); //sets to handle to signaled
```

Do you agree with this?

Comment: Since C99 lacks a thread library, and at a quick glance this looks nothing like the thread library proposed for C1x, please add a platform or library tag.

Comment: If you want meaningful advice you'll have to describe what your problem is. I would comment that you are creating an auto reset event which basically don't work. An event might be a solution to your problem, but you haven't said what your problem is. You first line of code segment was wrong because you can't call WaitForSingleObject until you've created an object, hence my answer. We can't help you until you start to help yourself and explain what your goals are.

Comment: @David I think Its clear from the code, I want to create a thread if its not already running. I would be creating it by the press on a button control.

Comment: that wasn't absolutely clear. Anyway you don't need an event and the answers already tell you what to do.

Comment: I've updated my answer to make it more explicitly address the problem as clarified by your comment.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you don't actually want to test whether the thread is finished, but instead want to know whether or not it has started. You would normally do this as follows:

```
HANDLE hThread = NULL;//do this during initialization
...
if (!hThread)
   hThread = CreateThread(......);
```

Once you know it has started (`hThread` not `NULL`) then you can test for it being completed with the `WaitForSingleObject` method that you are already aware of, or with [`GetExitCodeThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683190%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Your thread handle is uninitialized. You can't use `WaitForSingleObject()` on garbage handles. Are you trying to tell the status of a thread that has been created earlier, and restart it if it has died? Then you need to keep track of the first thread handle.

Comment: For this reason, it is good practice to always set unintialized HANDLEs to NULL, and then check whether they are NULL or not before using them. Functions like CreateThread returns NULL when they fail.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you mean [`GetExitCodeThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683190%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Edit.

```
hThread = CreateEvent(0, 0, 1, 0); //sets to handle to signaled
```

Thread handle becomes signaled when thread finished. This allows to wait for thread end using Wait* operations. Your code creates event handle, and not thread.